Get Current URL from a PHTML, inside Amasty Promo Banners Template - Magento 2
Amasty Promo Banner, template banner.phtml
All solutions that i tried get not current url but this:
https://magento.ddev.site/amasty_banners/banner/ajax/?_=1717758947843&banners%5B0%5D=&banners%5B1%5D=&banners%5B2%5D=&banners%5B3%5D=&banners%5B4%5D=&banners%5B5%5D=&banners%5B6%5D=&banners%5B7%5D=&context%5BcurrentCategory%5D=1711&sections%5B0%5D=10&sections%5B1%5D=4&sections%5B2%5D=15&sections%5B3%5D=14&sections%5B4%5D=5&sections%5B5%5D=2&sections%5B6%5D=22&sections%5B7%5D=1

And current url is https://magento.ddev.site/etikettendrucker-zubehoer/etikettendrucker/mini-desktop-drucker/
Any Idea?

I think you have installed the PWA venia?

no, i installed amasty/module-promo-banners and i want to get the URL of the current page on which  banner is located.

go to the template and use the magento URL Interface , it will return you the current URL

@iskander you can use below code for get current url from a phtml
$block->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true])
